# Kendo UI upload control remove firing after save when multiple set to false

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using the Kendo Upload control and need to allow the user to only upload one file at a time.  I set the multiple option to false on the client side and this works.  However, if a user uploads a file and then immediately tried to upload a second file, the removeUrl is called first which gets passed a string array of file names.  Here is the problem, when I save a file I am renaming the file to a name using guid values and creating a database table entry to associate the file with the user.  I need a way to reset the filename to the guid after the file is uploaded and its name is displayed?  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing the [Files configuration](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/upload#configuration-files) option. With that, you should be able to reset the displayed file names to any name you choose.